# SoundCloud API - genres and filter parameter of /tracks endpoint

Tags: api, soundcloud

I am using the SoundCloud API for a web application.
With the **/tracks** endpoint, I have two troubles below.

### 1. When I send a request with an invalid genres parameters, does the /tracks endpoint return 503 (Service Unavailable)?

When I intentionally use a condition which will not match any tracks **with the q parameter** like

```
http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks?q=ewkqtieorak&client_id=MY_CLIENT_ID&format=json&_status_code_map%5B302%5D=200
```

, responses are empty array as I expect, but **with the genres parameter** like

```
http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks?genres=hoge&client_id=MY_CLIENT_ID&format=json&_status_code_map%5B302%5D=200
```

, responses are always 503 (I tried about 500 times).

The /tracks endpoint return status 503 so often even with existing genres that I am not sure it means there are not such genres or SoundCloud is having a server trouble. Are there any ways to distinguish them?

---

### 2. It seems that the filter parameter doesn't work correctly.

Example requests are below. I wanted streamable tracks and added "streamable" as a filter parameter, but response tracks include some unstreamable tracks. Am I using it incorrectly?

```
http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks?filter=streamable&genres=electronica&client_id=MY_CLIENT_ID&format=json
```

```
http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks?filter=streamable&order=hotness&genres=jazz%2Cclassical&bpm[from]=0&bpm[to]=100&created_at[from]=2011-11-24%2000%3A00%3A00&created_at[to]=2012-02-22%2000%3A00%3A00&limit=5&client_id=MY_CLIENT_ID&format=json&_status_code_map[302]=200
```

```
http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks?filter=streamable&order=hotness&genres=jazz%2Cclassical&bpm[from]=0&bpm[to]=100&created_at[from]=2012-01-03%2000%3A00%3A00&created_at[to]=2012-04-02%2000%3A00%3A00&limit=30&client_id=MY_CLIENT_ID&format=json&_status_code_map[302]=200
```